# Can hydrogen on platinum reduce carboxylic acids and esters?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, carbonyl-compounds

Can $\ce{H2/Pt}$ reduce carboxylic acids and esters?

I am confused about the reducing nature of hydrogen in presence of platinum. In some books, it reduces carboxylic acid and ester while in others, not. I have checked Finar and Boyd books for it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*This is based off my memory, as far as I can remember what my teacher taught me.*

---

Note, instead of $\ce{Pt}$, you can go for $\ce{Ni}$ (or Raney Nickel) or even $\ce{Pd}$ as a catalyst.

Functional groups such as acid halide, cyanide, nitro, aldehyde, ketone, alkene, and alkyne are **easily reduced** by $\ce{H2/Ni}$.  Some other groups can be reduced with $\ce{H2/Ni}$ as well, but if someone's asking you a question in an exam, they want you to refer to the list of groups which are *easily reduced* (more in the reactivity order below).  So the answer in your case would be a *no*.

#### Next, here's a reactivity order:

First, the groups which are easily reduced:

$$\begin{align} \text{acid halide} > \ce{R-C#C-R} > \ce{R-C=C-R} > \ce{R-CHO} > \\ &\text{ketone}>  \ce{R-CN} > \ce{R-NO2} > \ldots \end{align}$$

Then the groups that are reduced only with difficulty:

$$ \ldots > \ce{R-X} > \text{benzene} > \ce{R-COOH} > \text{amide} > \text{ester} > \text{acid anhydride}$$

$\ce{R-X}$ would require temperatures around $\pu{50^\circ C}$, benzene would require a temperature of about $\pu{100^\circ C}$ and groups from carboxylic acid to acid anhydride would require temperatures around $200-\pu{250^\circ C}$.