Does H2/Ni reduce carboxylic acids in the presence of heat?
I came across a question that I was confused about. I'm aware that H2/Ni is generally preferred for ketones, aldehydes etc. and cannot reduce carboxylic acids/esters/amides at low temperatures, but this question specifies heat which is causing the confusion.

Here, Q is maleic acid and V is the product you're supposed to find. The answer says that V is a cyclic anhydride. I understand the reasoning behind the answer, but wouldn't the presence of heat also allow H2/Ni to reduce the carboxylic acids too?

It depends somewhat on the temperature and hydrogen pressure used, but the answer the examiner is expecting is succinic acid from reduction of the double bond.

H2/Ni is generally preferred for alkenes. It's for C=C bonds not C=O, even if you could make it work one way or another.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/75091/can-hydrogen-on-platinum-reduce-carboxylic-acids-and-esters

Reducing carboxylic acid using just Raney nickel will give poor to no yield, no matter how strong you provide heat: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Attempted-reduction-with-sodium-borohydride-and-Raney-nickel_tbl1_254365472. An addition reducer is given along with it, in this case sodium borohydride.

I'm not sure, I searched it up beforehand and a comment on another stack exchange post essentially said that it could as long as the temperature was sufficient. This question specifically mentioned heat as a condition which is what caused the confusion.

Since the product is an anhydride, then it V is succinic anhydride.
